# Neo4j delete swapped duplicates in results

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to find method-pairs that read or write the same field, for this i wrote this query:

```
match (c:Class)-[:DECLARES]->(m1:Method), (c)-[:DECLARES]-(m2:Method), (c)-[:DECLARES]-(f:Field), (m1)-[:WRITES|READS]->(f), (m2)-[:WRITES|READS]->(f) 
return m1.name, m2.name, f.name
```

Now i have the problem, that there are several duplicates in the results.

[image]

I want every "m1.name" and "m2.name" pair to be unique. Is there a way to filter out results that are swaped versions of other results?

Answer (score 0):

If you enforce a specific ordering of the `Method` nodes' native IDs, that will produce distinct `Method` name pairs (assuming method names are unique):

```
MATCH
  (c:Class)-[:DECLARES]->(m1:Method),
  (c)-[:DECLARES]-(m2:Method),
  (c)-[:DECLARES]-(f:Field),
  (m1)-[:WRITES|READS]->(f),
  (m2)-[:WRITES|READS]->(f)
WHERE ID(m1) < ID(m2)
RETURN m1.name, m2.name, f.name
```